# Error With Google Chrome After Suspending Computer

Tags: suspend, google-chrome

Google Chrome does not function properly after Ubuntu Suspend is activated and then computer starts back up. I have to kill all the Google Chrome processes and open Google Chrome back up for it to work properly. This is what happens when I scroll on a Youtube page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCUPz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling it with
sudo apt reinstall google

but you should use brave instead because google is ad ware
and also brave is base no google so their the same just on ad ware
how to install brave

sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl

curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -

echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install brave-browser

Comment: I tried: `sudo apt reinstall google-chrome-stable` but that did not fix the problem.